# How to make Chat Application in Android Using XMPP and GCM

Tags: android

I want to make a chat application using XMPP and GCM. but i didn't find some good tutorial or solution. I am using smack library for XMPP client and there are lots of jar files available. Please tell me which jar file should i use. 
And what is my next step.
Please help me i am stuck from more then 2 weeks,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build a chat application using XMPP, you probably do not need GCM, since a server implementing XMPP would be sufficient for your needs (an XMPP server simply pushes messages, so why use GCM here?).

I have used **Openfire** as XMPP server and **Smack** for XMPP client to make a basic chat application. But you can find other open source (or paid) XMPP server implementations from [this link](https://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/)

And yes, there are not much simple tutorials about that, but you can still find a lot of sample code and work your way around them.
May it be easy.